# Analysis Doubt on sequence and series of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have seen in Rudin the following "if a compact class of bounded continuous functions on a compact metric space is not equi-continuous then that class contains a sequence which has no equi-continuous sub-sequence". Is this correct ? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is. Let $F$ be a non-equicontinuous set of functions $f:X\to Y$ (but of course, we assume that each $f$ is continuous). We know there exists $\varepsilon>0$ and $x_0\in X$ such that for each $\delta>0$, there exists $f\in F$ such that $d(x,x_0)<\delta$ does not imply $d(f(x),f(x_0))<\varepsilon$. So with such an $\varepsilon$ an $x_0$ in mind, simply choose the function which fails for $\delta=1/n$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$. I don't think you need the bounded or compact domain conditions for this to work. Perhaps Rudin is pointing out that the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem gives not only sufficient, but also necessary conditions for a compact function space?